# Using root to access and modify protected database on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, root

I’m trying to create an app that is able to access and modify a protected database within `/data/data/`. This process obviously requires root privileges and I am testing this on a rooted device. The general code to access the SQLite database is complete and works against a test database that is located elsewhere (on `/sdcard/`).

However when I want the application to access the database within `/data/data/`, it obviously fails as I am trying to access it as a normal user. I have read on the topic of using the `su` binary on Android for a bit now, and as far as I understand it usually used to execute shell commands only.

So my initial idea of making this work was to simply change the permissions of the file when the application starts, and change it back when it quits. So before actually bothering with implementing that in the application itself, I used my file explorer to change the permission to `rw-rw-rw-`. However my application was still not able to open the database.

My next idea was to use the `sqlite3` program directly from the shell, but I found out, that my ROM does not come with it, so I would have to distribute it myself (*Titanium Backup* seems to do that).

However there is something that makes me wonder if there might not be a better way: I am using [Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer) as my file explorer and it has a built-in way to browse *any* SQLite database. Given that it does not seem to ship with a custom `sqlite3` binary, and that my phone does not have one itself, the access seems to happen using the normal Java tools. But how does the app get root rights then?

Is there a way to make an Android application run as root? Or did I forget setting something for the permissions earlier which prevented me from accessing it? Or does anyone know how *Root Explorer* does it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot raise the permissions of an already running process as far as I know. The simplest answer would be to copy it somewhere using the root shell / command line edit it, then copy it back as root again. And yes, I did read your question, just didn't explain the answer fully. Hopefully it's clear now. Not sure if root explorer does that  or something else, but it would work.